# Создание двумерного массива с++

Tags: c++, массивы

```
using vector = bool*[4];
vector* matrix[3];

matrix[0] = new vector; // !!!
```

cannot convert 'bool**' to 'bool* (*)[4]' in assignment

Никак не могу понять в чем проблема...

Comment: А почему просто не написать bool** ptr = new bool*[n] и после ptr[i] = new bool[m]? получится матрица n*m логических элементов.

Comment: я бы так и написал, но в задании сказано, что создать массив надо именно так

Comment: Как сказано? Сомневаюсь, что там сказано создавать его неверно... Дайте-та **точную** формулировку задания.

Comment: Если вас так учат создавать двумерные массивы, то мне страшно представить, что дальше будет...

Comment: using vector = bool*[4];
    vector* matrix[3];

    matrix[0] = new vector[1];
    // вот так почему то заработало
    // вопрос: почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что оператор `new` является функцией, которая не может принять тип `bool* (*)[4]`, потому тип автоматически преобразовывается в указатель на элемент массива(как и в других функциях), то есть в `bool**`, и, соответственно, оператор `new` вернет указатель на `bool**`, но типом элемента массива `matrix` является указатель на `bool* (*)[4]`.

Чтобы исправить, или не нужно создать элементы через оператор `new` или же `matrix` должен хранить `bool**`.

А вообще, по мне, вы хотели сделать:

```
using vector = bool* [4];
vector matrix[3]; //пока не ясно что от вас требуют
```

Этого будет достаточно. `matrix` содержит 3 элемента типа статического массива, и вместо его не можете запихнуть динамический массив(указатель на него). И, например , `matrix[0]` будет именем первого массива, а имени массива нельзя присвоить что то другое, ее можно просто использовать или преобразовать в указатель элемента:
bool** arr1 = matrix[0];

Comment: 1) `new-expression` — это не функция. 2) Тип `bool* (*)[4]` — это _указатель_ на массив из четырёх элементов типа `bool*`. C помощью `new` можно выделять память для указателей. Данный тип не преобразуется в `bool**`. 3) `указатель на bool* (*)[4]` — это `bool* (**)[4]`. Типом элемента массива `matrix` является `bool* (*)[4]`, а не `bool* (**)[4]`. 4) Здесь `new vector`, тип `vector` — это тип `bool*[4]`. Такая запись эквивалентна `new bool*[4]`.

Comment: @wololo, 1. однако здравствуйте. new-expression содержит new оператор , а оператор есть функция. 2. Никто не говорил, что это не так.  Не преобразуется в bool**, но передается как bool** 3. Не понятно: сами прочтите что вы написали. 4. Тоже не понятно о чем вы. Как может быть статическое выделение памяти быть эквивалентным  с динамическим выделением, и кто говорил, что vector различный от bool*[4] тип?

Comment: 4) Здесь я хотел сказать, что выражение `new vector` возвращает указатель `bool**` по той причине, что оно интерпретируется как выражение `new bool*[4]`. Про эквивалентность статического и динамического выделения не понял. Вроде никто из нас такого не писал?

Comment: 1) `оператор есть функция`. `sizeof` — тоже оператор, значит ли это, что `sizeof` — функция? 2) `Никто не говорил, что это не так` В вашем же ответе: `new ... не может принять тип bool* (*)[4]` — это не верно. `new` может принимать указательные типы. 3) Фразу `var является указатель на int` я воспринимаю как `var имеет тип int*`. Вы написали: `элемент matrix является указатель на bool* (*)[4]`, что я воспринимаю как `элемент matrix имеет тип bool* (**)[4]`. Это не так.